# Jquery array contents not shown directly after clicking first radio button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following html:

```
if(isset($_POST['itemid']))
{
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered table-rounded errorcattable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan='4'>Error categorieeen</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bijbehorend punt</th>
      <th>Categorienaam</th>
      <th>Error</th>
      <th>fix</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
        for( $i = 0; $i < count( $getErrorCategories->data ); $i++ ) :
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td id='<?php echo $getErrorCategories->data[$i][' item ']; ?>'>
          <?php echo $getErrorCategories->data[$i]['item']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $getErrorCategories->data[$i]['c_error_cat_name']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $getErrorCategories->data[$i]['error']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $getErrorCategories->data[$i]['fix']; ?><br/>
          <input type='radio'>OK<br/>
          <input type='radio'>NOK</td>
      </tr>
      <?php 
          endfor;
      ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
}
```

By using the following jquery code, I store the table its contents (that are in the for loop) in an array:

```
var ajaxResult = [];
$('.radionok').each(function() {

  $(this).click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        itemid: $(this).attr('alt')
      },
      url: "cl.php",
      success: function(data) {

        if ($.inArray($('.errorcattable', data).prop('outerHTML'), ajaxResult) == -1) {
          ajaxResult.push($('.errorcattable', data).prop('outerHTML'));
        }
      }
    });

    console.log(ajaxResult);
    $(".errorcattable_display").show()
    $('.errorcattable_display').html(ajaxResult);

  });

});
```

As you can see, when clicking on the button that has radionok as class, the contents of the array (i.e. ajaxResult) should be shown. However, the contents are only shown when I click on the second radio button etc. So when clicking on the first radio button nothing happens:

[image]

When I click the second radio button, the table of the first is shown, but the table belonging to the second button is again not shown while it is stored in the array:

[image]

The same occurs when clicking the third radio button (the first and second tables are then shown but not the third) etc. I want the script to directly show the first table when the first not ok radio button is clicked, then when the second not ok button is clicked, second table should be shown besides the first table etc.

Could someone explain why this behavior is happening and how can I modify the script such that it suits my needs?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I needed to move `$(".errorcattable_display").show().html(ajaxResult);` into the success function of the ajax call.